# error: cannot find symbol variable BOOKMARKS_URI

Tags: android

After Targeting SDK version 23 I get the bellow error.

## Code

```
CursorLoader cLoader = new CursorLoader(context,
android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
projection, 
null, 
null, 
sortDescriptors.objectAtIndex(0).getProperty());
```

## Error

```
error: cannot find symbol variable BOOKMARKS_URI
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BOOKMARKS_URI` was removed in API Level 23, along with [a variety of other things from `Bookmarks`](http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes/android.provider.Browser.html).